# Deallocating memory from a private class variable

Tags: c++

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


using namespace std;

class myClass{

public:
    int *num1;
    myClass();


};

myClass::myClass(){
    num1 = new int[1];
    num1[0] = 10;
}


int main()
{
    myClass *myclass;

    myclass = new myClass[10];

    cout << myclass[0].num1[0] << endl;

    delete &myclass[0];
    cout << myclass[0].num1[0] << endl;

}
```

I want to delete the first instance of myclass (myclass[0]).

This code does not run correctly, it fails during the delete part. There is probably something I am missing.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: You can't delete only the first instance, you have one `delete` for every `new`. You deallocate blocks of memory, not objects. Use `delete[] myClass` to deallocate all the memory and every object in it.

Comment: As a side issue, `myClass` has a leak of its own.  You need to `delete [] num1;` in the dtor.

Comment: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6101039/Modern%20C++.pdf

Comment: As another side issue: if you're not that familiar with C++, note that you can do most things using stack-allocated objects and collections (vectors, maps etc.) of them.  Doing this makes your code 100x safer.  You generally don't ever need to call `new`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a function inside of your class the handles the deletion of its private members, maybe called `FreeMem(int index)`

```
void myClass::FreeMem()
{
    delete [] num1
}
```

But honestly, freeing memory of an object without the use of a destructor in this sort of a program is hazardous and downright bad practice. I would recommend freeing the memory in your destructor, so when the object terminates it frees the memory,

```
myClass::~myClass()
{
    delete [] num1;
}
```

Another thing to note on, if you're only creating one value in your dynamic variable, it would be easier to write it as:

```
int * pnum = new int;
//or in your class..
pnum = new int;
```

among other things, you have a lot of flaws in your program. I would recommend re-reading up on classes again.

Comment: I am a little too far into my program to fix this design. But your FreeMem() suggestion will work, thanks.

Comment: Ok, it seems to work in my little program above. But when I try it in my main program I get *** glibc detected ***  error. =/

Comment: @user1773070 Your code is probably double freeing because you haven't designed `myClass` to correctly manage its own resources, including copying.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot delete just a portion of an array created with `new`. `new` allocates a block of memory which can only be `delete`ed all together.

If you want an object to free its own internal data you'll have to arrange for the class, which should encapsulate and hide its own internal resources, to do that itself.

If you want a smaller block of memory holding the array you allocated, then you must allocate a smaller block and move the contents that you wish to keep into the new block, and then delete the entire old block:

```
int *arr = new int[10];

int *tmp = new int[9];
std::copy(arr+1, arr+10, tmp);
delete [] arr;
arr = tmp;
```

---

You need to design your class to manage its own resources, and to handle copying or moving. Your current `myClass` allocates an array but relies on other code to handle cleaning up. This is not a good way to go about doing this, because often no other code is in a good position to do the correct thing, and even when you could you'll very frequently make mistakes.

Since you're allocating in the constructor you need a destructor that handles deallocation. And then since you implement one of three special operations (copy-ctor, copy-assignment, destructor) you need to consider implementing them all. (This is called 'The Rule of Three'. In C++11 it becomes 'The Rule of Five' with the addition of move-ctors and move assignment.)

```
class myClass {
public:
    myClass();

    // destructor to handle destroying internal resources correctly
    ~myClass();

    // copy constructor and copy assignment operator, to handle copying correctly
    myClass(myClass const &rhs);
    myClass &operator=(myClass const &rhs);

    // move constructor and move assignment operator, to handle moves correctly (C++11)
    myClass(myClass && rhs);
    myClass &operator= (myClass &&rhs);

private:
   int *num1; // private so external code can't screw it up

public:
   // limited access to num1
   int size() const { if (num1) return 1; else return 0; }
   int &operator[] (size_t i) { return num1[i]; }
};
```

You can implement the constructor just as you did, or you could use the initializer list and C++11 uniform initialization:

```
myClass::myClass() : num1(new int[1]{10}) {}
```

Now, the destructor you want depends on the semantics you want the class to have, and the particular invariants you want to maintain. 'value' semantics are the norm in C++ (if you're familiar with Java or C# those languages encourage or require 'reference' semantics for user defined types). Here's a destructor you might use if you want value semantics, and if you maintain an invariant that num1 always owns memory or is null.

```
myClass::~myClass() { delete num1; }
```

Copying and moving can be handled in different ways. If you want to disallow them entirely you can say (in C++11):

```
myClass::myClass(myClass const &rhs) = delete;
myClass &myClass::operator=(myClass const &rhs) = delete;

myClass::myClass(myClass && rhs) = delete;
myClass &myClass::operator= (myClass &&rhs) = delete;
```

Or if you want to allow copying and or moving (and maintain value semantics and the invariant mentioned above) then you can implement either or both of these pairs of functions:

```
myClass::myClass(myClass const &rhs) : num1( rhs.size() ? new int[1]{rhs[0]} : nullptr) {}
myClass &myClass::operator=(myClass const &rhs) {
    if (num1)
        num1[0] = rhs[0];
}

myClass::myClass(myClass && rhs) : num1(rhs.num1) { rhs.num1 = nullptr; } // remember to maintain the invariant that num1 owns the thing it points at, and since raw pointers don't handle shared ownership only one thing can own the int, and therefore only one myClass may point at it. rhs.num1 must be made to point at something else...
myClass &myClass::operator= (myClass &&rhs) { std::swap(num1, rhs.num1); } // steal rhs.num1 and leave it to rhs to destroy our own num1 if necessary. We could also destroy it ourselves if we wanted to.
```

With this implementation you can now treat a myClass object the same as you would an `int` or any other 'value' type. You no longer need to worry about managing its internal resources; it will take care of them itself.

```
int main() {
    std::vector<myClass> myclassvec(10);

    cout << myclassvec[0][0] << '\n';

    myclassvec.erase(myclassvec.begin()); // erase the first element

    cout << myclassvec[0][0] << '\n'; // access the new first element (previously the second element);
}
```